# Reusing java.util.Random instance vs creating a new instance every time

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, random, secure-random

The title pretty much summarizes it - we can create one instance of `java.util.Random` (or `SecureRandom`) and use it every time we need a random value or we can create a new instance every time on demand. Wondering which one is the *preferred* way and why?

To give some idea about the context: the random value is being generated inside an HTTP request handler, one per request, and I'm looking for the best combination for security and performance considering multi-threading.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html

Comment: There is no such thing as a "random number." Any time you see the word, "random," think "unpredictable." A number, all by itself, can't be unpredictable. What would that even mean?. A `java.util.Random` instance isn't a thing that gives you isolated random numbers: It's a thing that gives you an unpredictable _sequence_ of numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends.

Creating a single instance is obviously simpler and should be the default behaviour. Both `Random` and `SecureRandom` are threadsafe, and will therefore work just fine. First do the simple and correct thing that works, then measure your performance against your expected peak contention / peak perf budget, and analyze the results.

### `Random`

If you're using `Random` and the single instance approach is too slow, consider using `ThreadLocalRandom` if possible. The JavaDoc in `Random` suggests its usage nicely:

> Instances of `java.util.Random` are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same `java.util.Random` instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using `ThreadLocalRandom` in multithreaded designs.

It will only create an instance for each thread accessing it. The creation cost of a `Random` / `ThreadLocalRandom` instance is not insane, but it is higher than the creation of a "normal" object, so you should probably avoid creating a new instance for each incoming request. Creating one per thread is generally a nice sweet spot.

I would say that in modern applications with pooled threads, you should almost always use `ThreadLocalRandom` instead of `Random` - the randomness is the same, but the single-thread performance is much better.

#### `SecureRandom`

If you're using `SecureRandom`, though, `ThreadLocalRandom` is not an option. Again, do not guess, measure! Maybe using a single shared instance of a `SecureRandom` will be good enough. Test with your expected peak contention, and if the secure random instance turns out to be a bottleneck, only then think about ways to improve the situation.

Creating a `SecureRandom` instance is very costly, so you absolutely do not want to create one for each incoming request.

Depending on your application, a `ThreadLocal<SecureRandom>` may be an option. Still, I think that's an overkill, and a scheme similar to the [`Striped`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) class (with X `SecureRandom` instances created and accessed randomly to help prevent contention) may be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

If you need random numbers for information security, only a cryptographic RNG (such as `java.security.SecureRandom`) will do.  And for any cryptographic RNG, the simplest approach is to use only one thread-safe instance of it for the entire application to use (note that `SecureRandom` is thread-safe according to the documentation); there is generally no benefit to creating multiple instances of a cryptographic RNG, as they will all eventually have to be initialized with high-entropy ("unpredictable") data.

[Gathering such "unpredictable" data is not trivial](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Nondeterministic_Sources_and_Seed_Generation), and at least for your application, you need not worry about that when you use `SecureRandom`, which largely does this for you and includes a `setSeed` method you can use to add extra data to supplement its randomness.

Comment: Thanks for answering, can you please elaborate on the last part?